# Mysql create a dynamic insert

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a Dynamic sql insert, let's call generic insert, where I'll set the IN parameters like, IN pTableName VARCHAR(50), IN pTableTemp VARCHAR(50)
My idea is create a generic stored procedure where I can create dynamically all the process to create a Temporary Table something like this:

```
DECLARE vFields         LONGTEXT;

SELECT DISTINCT GROUP_CONCAT(TRIM(COLUMN_NAME)) INTO vFields FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
        WHERE table_name = pTableName;
SELECT vFields;
```

This process is to bring all the Column_names from the original table, it's possible to create a Temporary table using all the values set on the variable vFields?

Thanks.

Comment: Why? The purpose of this function is extremely unclear but seems to me like some kind of anti-pattern being implemented.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.The reason is I would like to create a stored procedure that I just pass 2 parameters: pTablename and pTableTemp and it creates the insert statement automatically. I don't know if I'm clear, but I'm very happy for your comment.Thank you

Comment: Why not just write an `INSERT` statement instead of having a procedure attempt to write one for you?